# Rendering multiple Images efficently

Tags: java, image, graphics, render, bufferedimage

I am prototyping a game where I need to render ~30 64x64 blocks to the Screen.
Normally I do stuff like that with libgdx, but I want to use the native Java methods this time.

For a sample test I load 10 blocks and render them - dropping my fps from around 300 to 35.
The Laptop I have here is kinda bad, but I didn't expect him to break down so early. If you could just take a look at my code and give me possible hints about how to render more efficently - that would be great. I guess I didn't grasp the concept of the BufferedImage and Graphics 100% too.

Btw, my specs are: 
* i5-2520M CPU @2.5GHZ (getting around 30% load while Debugging)
* 4GB Ram
* NO Gpu

-----------------CODE----------------------------------------

The Graphics and Image declarations:

```
public BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
public Graphics2D g;
```

The Loop

```
while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        unprocessed += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        GraphicUtil.setDelta(now - lastTime);
        lastTime = now;
        boolean shouldRender = true;

        while (unprocessed >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            gameTick();
            unprocessed -= 1;
            shouldRender = true;
        }

        if (shouldRender) {
            frames++;
            input.tick();
            render();
        }


        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer1 > 1000) {
            lastTimer1 += 1000;
            System.out.println(ticks + " ticks, " + frames + " fps");
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
```

The render()-method in my main Loop

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        return;
    }

    switch(currentScreenId) {
    case Screen.MENUSCREENID :
        menuScreen.handleInput();
        menuScreen.render();
        break;
    case Screen.HOWTOSCREENID :
        howToScreen.handleInput();
        howToScreen.render();
        break;
    case Screen.GAMESCREENID :

        gameScreen.handleInput();
        gameScreen.render();

        break;
    }

    Graphics g2 = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(GraphicUtil.toCompatibleImage(image), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g2.dispose();
    //

    bs.show();
}
```

The render()-Method in my gameScreen

```
public void render() {
    clearScreen(Color.BLACK);

    //Render blocks
    for(Block b : blocks.values()) {
        game.g.drawImage(blockImage, (int) b.getBounds().x, (int) b.getBounds().y, blockImage.getWidth(null), blockImage.getHeight(null), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## First

Convert the images to a compatible color model for the device, so they don't need to be converted on the fly...

```
GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
BufferedImage img = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height, image.getTransparency());
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(master, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

## Second

If the blocks aren't changing (ie are a background), paint them to a `BufferedImage` (buffer) when you load them and then paint the buffer to the `Graphics` context instead.

I'd also encourage you to pass the `Graphics` context you want to use to the `renderer` method, as it could change while you are painting.